# What optical system could perform a multiplication/convolution of several rectangular pulses with different widths?

Tags: optics, mathematics

**Statement**

There is a following multiplication/convolution of $n$ rectangular pulses with different widths
$$
f(x)=\mathrm{rect}(c_1x)\ast\mathrm{rect}(c_2x)\ast\ldots\ast\mathrm{rect}(c_mx)
$$
or
$$
f(x)=\prod\limits_{n=1}^m f_n(x).
$$

**Question**
What optical system could perform a convolution of several rectangular pulses with different widths in general sense? Means there is no pre-requirements in the statement.

**P.S.**
Problem has mathematical roots and optical system is needed to be an illustrative example.

**UPD.1 19.01.2019**

***Clarification.***
Let's focus on the implementation of multiplication operation. Let us want to implement mathematical multiplication operation of two where a) $m=2$ and b) $m=3$ functions.

We come to the following **question**:

*What optical system implements the multiplication of intensities of coherent beams of light come from different directions? How does the schematic diagram look like?*

**UPD.2 20.01.2019**

In fact the question is about optical multiplier of intensities principal scheme.

Comment: Optical systems are good at Fourier transforms.  Can you perform your convolution in the Fourier plane, then convert it back?

Comment: @DDuck, thank your for the feedback. I've updated the question.